# Eagle CAD: Use schematic as part

Tags: eaglecad

I am very new to using Eagle CAD. One thing that I am trying to do is use a schematic that is not in a library as a part in my main schematic. I'm not able to find anything that allows me to do that. Whenever I use the "Open" option in the "file", it just closes my main schematic and opens the schematic that I selected. How should I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How use 'Hierarchical Blocks' in Eagle?.. nesting schematics within schematics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49062/how-use-hierarchical-blocks-in-eagle-nesting-schematics-within-schematics)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, this does, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Eagle *Design Block* if you feel like the circuit part could be re-used multiple time.

But maybe you just want to copy some parts + connections from one schematics to an another.  In this case:

1. Open both schematics. You actually have to start Eagle twice.
2. Go the schematics, from which you want to copy stuff.
3. Click on `group` and select whatever you want to copy. It will be highligted.
4. Click on `copy` + right-click anywhere on the schematic -> `Copy: Group`
5. Go to schematics where you want to place the selected part, click `paste` and it should appear. Place it with left click.

Please note, that the PCB routing design will not be copied this way. You have to route it again. If you want to copy that as well, use *Design Block*.